# ¿Cómo organizar el código PHP, HTML y JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un problema, es que, no se me ocurre cómo organizar el código para que funcionen ambos lenguajes.

Y es que si lo organizo de esta manera `no loguea` pero `muestra el código javascript`, debido a que ya está definido el id.

```php
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {header('Location: personajes'); exit();} ?>
<html> //Aquí va el formulario. </html>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $u=$_POST['usuarioingresado'];
    if(!empty($u))
    {   
        $c=$_POST['contraingresada'];
        if(!empty($c))
        {
        include 'lib/con-pdo.php';
        $ce=strtoupper(hash('whirlpool', $c));
        $usql=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = :u or Email = :u and Contra = :ce");
        $stmt1=$db->prepare($usql);
        $stmt1->execute(array(":u" => $u, ":ce" => $ce));
            if($stmt1->fetchColumn()==1)
            {
                session_start(); $_SESSION['usuario'] = $u;header('Location: personajes');  
            }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='Los datos de inicio de sesión son incorrectos.'</script>";}
        }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar una contraseña.'</script>";}
    }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar un usuario o e-mail.'</script>";}
}
?>
```

En cambio de esta manera `si loguea`, pero `no muestra el JavaScript` debido a que no está definido el div.

```html
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {header('Location: personajes'); exit();} ?>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $u=$_POST['usuarioingresado'];
    if(!empty($u))
    {   
        $c=$_POST['contraingresada'];
        if(!empty($c))
        {
        include 'lib/con-pdo.php';
        $ce=strtoupper(hash('whirlpool', $c));
        $usql=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = :u or Email = :u and Contra = :ce");
        $stmt1=$db->prepare($usql);
        $stmt1->execute(array(":u" => $u, ":ce" => $ce));
            if($stmt1->fetchColumn()==1)
            {
                session_start(); $_SESSION['usuario'] = $u;header('Location: personajes');  
            }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='Los datos de inicio de sesión son incorrectos.'</script>";}
        }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar una contraseña.'</script>";}
    }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar un usuario o e-mail.'</script>";}
}
?>
<html> //Aquí va el formulario. </html>
```

Comment: Por que usas javascript para  mostrar los errores ?. SI estas renderizando el HTML del formulario en el mismo PHP , porque no muestras los mensajes dentro del mismo HTML que tienes entre <html></html> ?  de esa forma te evitas pensar donde lo pones.

Comment: Es lo que hace el javascript, el html está separado del php, pero edita un <p id='error'>, mostrando tal error.